# AWS Database not connecting with Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, pymysql

I am running a python program called MyCode.py that uses pymysql to connect to a AWS database and pull from it. When I run it in Jenkins using in the shell, the python packages are successfully installed however the pymysql connection fails to connect and times out after MyCode.py is called. When I run MyCode.py through my Mac OSx terminal, it runs perfectly and can successfully pull from the database. Any idea if the code I use to call my python script disrupts pymysql from connecting?

Jenkins shell script:

```
ls -la
virtualenv FullTests
. FullTests/bin/activate
pip install pandas
pip install pymysql
pip install logger
pip install requests
ls -la
python FullTests.py
deactivate
```

MyCode.py (Snippet)

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='production-cluster.cluster123-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com', port=3306, user='reader', passwd='somepassword, db='metrics', connect_timeout=10)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.callproc('metrics.GetReaderData')
result = cur.fetchall()
return result
```

Comment: Would you please add some pieces of information about, what is the status of security groups (for AWS RDS) ? I think python code is not related with the problem.

Comment: Sorry my fault, you have already accessed RDS with console. So, you thought pymysql  is curprit.

Comment: You're all good. Yes, I think there is an additional step in my Jenkins shell script where I need to give AWS some permission. Not sure how to do so :/